# MS Access XP record is #deleted special char

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, windows-10, oracle9i

I am upgrading old system that runs under Windows XP to Windows 10.

One of the application have been developped in MS Access XP linked to an Oracle Database (Oracle 9i - instant client ODBC driver 32bit).

My computer is in French, MS Access is in french.

When I run a SQL line :

```
SELECT LIST_NAME FROM WZ_LISTS_HD WHERE LIST_REL1 = 'Produit'
```

I get the following result :
[Summary Access vs SQL Explorer Windows 10 vs Windows XP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJpFT.png)

In Windows 10 (access), I get a #Deleted for each record with a special character (in this case "è" or "é"). I try with an homemade SQL Explorer and I get no #Deleted but I don't have the special character.

In my old system (Windows XP) with my SQL explorer, I get the complete recordset with special characters.

Anyone have an idea how to work this out? Most of post about #Deleted is suggesting each database corrupt or "needed for db compaction". In my case, I can get the records with my old system without a problem. There is users working with the database everyday. Hence, database is ok.

"Compacting database" makes no sense since I don't use a mdb (Access main db files).

I tried changing my windows keyboard and language feature. Didn't work.

Once last thing, I've done the same upgrade (Windows XP -> Windows 7) for some user under Windows 7. Worked like a charm. No #Deleted record. It seems to be related to how Windows 10 handles language.

This is the TNSNAMES.ORA File content.

```
SYNDATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = serveur-oracle)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracle6)
    )
  )
```

The ODBC information goes as follow :

[ODBC Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXxw5.png)

Here is the part of code that call the SQL request :

[VBA Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDmdE.png)

Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the ODBC driver. Access tends to display _#Deleted_ when there's a problem accessing the actual value. Are you accessing through a pass-through query or through Access? What's your connection string (with server/pass censored)?

Comment: I edited the original post to add the information you asked.

You seem to be right. I created a MDB file with a table and 2 fields. I populated with some words with and some words without special char. I did a request on the table and Access is showing everything without a problem. Hence, the problem seems to come from the ODBC driver.

Comment: I am not sure about the "pass-through" or "through access". I did not right the VBA code. But here is the failing bit of code  (sorry for formating) :

Comment: That's through Access (you use Access SQL, and let Access translate it to Oracle SQL.) It's prone to errors. Using ADO and a direct connection to the Oracle database can probably resolve this.

Comment: Finally posted code as picture, I was not able to make the proper formating. Please see below.

Comment: I will start looking into this. Have an idea where I should start? I am not too familiar with VBA and it is under Access...
The thing I am wondering is why is it working under Windows XP and Windows 7. It is the same MS Access (same install CD).

Answer (score 0):

To use passthrough queries instead of normal recordsets:

```vb
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQuerydef("", "SELECT LIST_NAME FROM WZ_LISTS_HD WHERE LIST_REL1 = 'Produit'")
qd.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("LIST_NAME").Connect 'Reuse the connect
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly) 'Minimal chance to see weird things with snapshots
```

When using passthrough queries, the SQL needs to be valid for Oracle (PL/SQL) and not for Access. They are executed directly on the backend database, limiting the opportunity for Access to do weird stuff. You do need to use `UPPER` instead of `UCASE`, for example.